# Unable to late bind excel from Access VBA - Workbooks.Open doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I would like to start removing my references to late bind as Mr. Fenton suggests.  However, I tried to late bind Excel, exactly as everything I have looked up, and could not fix it until I added 
"Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3".

My references currently are:

```
Visual Basic for Applications
Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library
Microsoft Data Access Components Installed Version
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft XML,v6.0
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3.
```

Testing was done with Windows 10, Access 2013 Runtime and accdb.

Here is the top part of the Function with the declarations and section with the error:

```
On Error GoTo errHandle:

Dim FileToImport As Variant
Dim FilesLoaded As String
Dim csvStr As String
DoCmd.Hourglass False
Dim Loc As Integer

Loc = Forms!StartPage.LocationID

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim ofile As Object
Dim fdialog As Object
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim uid As String
uid = Forms!AppLoginFrm!FullName
Dim stp As String
Dim thestr As String
Dim inboundrs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ChkInbound As String
Dim repprg As Long
Dim ExcelApp As Object
Dim fname As String
Dim rng As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim xlsheet1 As Object
Dim skiphead As Integer
stp = format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
Dim tmpfile As String

tmpfile = TempPath()

tmpfile = tmpfile & "tmpLoad.txt"

skiphead = 2
Set fdialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
fdialog.Filters.Clear
fdialog.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls,*.xlsx"

    fdialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    If fdialog.Show = 0 Then
    Exit Function
    End If


Set ofile = fso.CreateTextFile(tmpfile, True, False)


     ofile.WriteLine """Location""" & "," & """YardTrack""" & "," & """Dir""" & "," & """Seq"""...

        For Each FileToImport In fdialog.SelectedItems

    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With ExcelApp
    .Workbooks.Open FileToImport

        .DisplayAlerts = -1
        .Visible = -1
        .Windows(1).Visible = -1

        Set xlsheet1 = .Worksheets(1)
        Set rng = xlsheet1.UsedRange

            If xlsheet1.cells(1, 1).Value = "TOT-CARS" Then
                skiphead = 3
            End If
        For i = skiphead To rng.rows.count
            csvStr = csvStr & Chr(34) & rng(i, 1) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & rng(i, 2) & Chr...

            ofile.Write csvStr
            csvStr = ""
            Next

              ofile.Write Chr(34) & csvStr & Chr(34) & vbCrLf
            ExcelApp.Workbooks.Close
            Set rng = Nothing
            Set xlsheet1 = Nothing
      End With
            FilesLoaded = FilesLoaded & vbCrLf & fileName(FileToImport)

        Next FileToImport


ExcelApp.Quit
ofile.Close
Set fdialog = Nothing
```

Questions:

1) Did I miss a constant for Open??  The point was to remove references, but to make this work I had to add one. :(

2) What reference should I try to remove next?  Honestly I'm a little scared after the last one, but I want the program as stable as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For starters - use a variable to refer to your workbook. `Set xlsheet1 = .Worksheets(1)` - this should refer to a workbook parent, but is currently referring to the application instance...

Comment: You don't need to create new `Excel Application` for each iteration either. You can keep the application object and open/close workbooks. will save some time/memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I copy/pasted out of my personal code stuffz. It is a generic late binding template for working with excel. You can increase your late bdingin efficiency by setting up a module with all the excle constants. Pretty nifty stuff.

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function getFile() As String
    Dim f As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If f.Show Then
        If f.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            getFile = f.SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function ConvUNC(filePath As String) As String
    Dim fileR As String
    fileR = Replace(filePath, "C:", "C$")
    ConvUNC = "\\" & Environ$("computername") & "\" & fileR
End Function

Public Sub UploadExcel()
    On Error GoTo UpLoadExcel_Err
    Dim fileP As String, FileDir As String
    Dim oXL As Object, sheet As Object
    Dim bringOver As Variant

    fileP = getFile
    If fileP = "" Then GoTo CleanUp
    FileDir = Left(fileP, InStrRev(fileP, "\") - 1) & "\"

    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With oXL
        .WorkBooks.Open FileName:=FileDir & Dir$(fileP)
        Open NewTextFile For Output As #2
        For Each sheet In .Worksheets
            bringOver = .ActiveSheet.UsedRange
NextSheet:
            Erase bringOver
        Next sheet
    End With

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    DoEvents
    oXL.Quit
    oXL.Application.Quit
    Erase bringOver
    Exit Sub
UpLoadExcel_Err:
    MsgBox "An error has occured.  " & " " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " "
    GoTo CleanUp
    Resume
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

BigBen seems to have had the answer.  I just changed the workbook.  I also moved the CreateObject out of the loop as Krish suggested, because of course it should be out of the loop! :)

Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(FileToImport)

```
.DisplayAlerts = -1
.Visible = -1
.Windows(1).Visible = -1

Set xlsheet1 = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set rng = xlsheet1.UsedRange
```

Doug, I think you're right I should make a reusable function.  I haven't done the ConvUNC.. probably should.  I can't use your code as is, because several excel uses use multiple select, but I think I can tweek it.

Thank you all for your help.